# Telegram Bot API Получить номер телефона

Tags: c#, telegram, api, бот

Задача: получить номер телефона пользователя используя Телеграмм бота. Использую это api https://core.telegram.org/bots/api. Там написано что нужно отправить пользователю KeyboardButton с параметром request_contact = true, но не написано как потом получить номер, мне нужно какого то слушателя подключать или теперь в каком то запросе номер будет передаваться?

Comment: вам просто придёт в ответ сообщение - контакт, если пользователь согласится